# Unable to clear the Input Fields

Tags: javascript

I have a very basic code. However I am not able to clear the  of the Year with the id (userYOB) on clicking the alert ok. The code works only for the  which asks for year. Its not just the clearing of  but I also want to bring the place holder back once alert is clicked ok.

Thanks for help.

[fiddle] http://jsfiddle.net/vineetgnair/j8zjjj9r/26/

```
var d = new Date();
var currentYear = d.getFullYear();



function test() {

    var userYearOfBirth = document.getElementById("userYOB").value;
    var authorisedAge = 19;
    var currentAge = parseInt(currentYear - userYearOfBirth);
    //console.log(currentAge);

    if (currentAge < authorisedAge) {
        alert("You are not authorised to visit the site");
        document.getElementById("userYOB").value = " ";
    } else {
        alert("Welcome to the site!");
        userYearOfBirth = " ";
    }

}
```

Comment: if you want to clear the textbox for year and also show the placeholder/watermark text then set the value to empty string document.getElementById("userYOB").value = "";

Answer (score 2):

In `else` part say

```
document.getElementById("userYOB").value= " ";
```

instead of

```
userYearOfBirth = " ";
```

Because `userYearOfBirth` is a simple string so updating it doesn't update the value of textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following lines after the else part,

```
    document.getElementById("userYOB").value= " ";
    document.getElementById("userMOB").value= " ";
    document.getElementById("userDOB").value= " ";
```

This will clear the fields and bring back the placeholder. The reason why

```
    userYearOfBirth  = " "
```

doesn't work is because in the following line the variable actually holds the value not the element itself,

```
   var userYearOfBirth = document.getElementById("userYOB").value;
```

It would be more advisable if you, replaced the above line with,

```
   var userYearOfBirth = document.getElementById("userYOB");
```

now you have the reference to the element in the variable. You can easily change the elements value by,

```
  userYearOfBirth.value = " ";
```

Personally, I prefer the latter method cause its less code. I hope this helps!! :)